# My database already have 20 row but when i save new row they start with id from 1

Tags: python, django, database

Curently, I import data to my database table with 20 rows already

When I use save() method to that table they start saved data with pk=1 lead to Error And they come true when pk=21

Can anyone help me with this although id column in my model is default I dont overwrite it

Comment: can you share your model code?

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The first (and probably best) option is to remove the ID values from the data you are importing and allow Django to manage the auto-incrementing PK value ([See docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#auto-incrementing-primary-keys)). If you are calling `.save()`, don't include the ID value in the model instance and this should solve your problem. If the `id` value is not `None`, this is where you can get out of sync.

If that doesn't work for your use-case (e.g. you need the ID values of the data you are importing to remain unchanged), the second and more complex option is to use the Django command `sqlsequencereset` ([Documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#sqlsequencereset)) which will return the sql statements that need to be executed to reset the auto-incrementing PK value to the current max ID + 1. In your django app, you could run the following code to execute these sql statements:

```
from django.db import connections
from django.core.management.color import no_style

# 'default' is the name of the database which may need to change
# execute the sequence_reset_sql command for all models in a specific 'APP_NAME'
sequence_sql = connections['default'].ops.sequence_reset_sql(
    no_style(), [apps.get_model(['APP_NAME'], model) for model in models])

# execute the sql statements
with connections['default'].cursor() as cursor:
    for sql in sequence_sql:
        cursor.execute(sql)
```

^ note this is for Django 1.11